# How can I get android GTS test suite?

Tags: android

I have downloaded CTS test suite via [CTS download link](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/downloads.html)

But, how can I get android GTS/XTS test suite?

GTS test suite like below pic
[image: gts picture]

Thanks

Comment: What, exactly, is the "GTS/XTS test suite"?

Comment: @CommonsWare  CTS is short for Compatibility Test Suite (CTS)

Comment: gts4.1-r1  the test plan such as *GtsLocationTestApp*

Comment: "CTS is short for Compatibility Test Suite (CTS)" -- yes, I am aware of that. I did not ask you what the CTS is. I asked you what the "GTS/XTS test suite" is. You are asking for the "GTS/XTS test suite", and it will increase your chances of getting an answer if you would explain exactly what this is, why you think it is publicly available, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare upgrade the description of my question. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Like CTS, GTS test suite is not a open source. Hence it is not available for public download. It is only available for the Android partners who have partnered with Google to preload Google mobile applications on android devices.

Comment: CTS test suite *is* open source, and the OP posted the official CTS test suite download link.